# Git diff does not make any sense

Tags: php, git, netbeans, bitbucket

When I run `git diff` on a PHP file that I have modified, it shows me the wrong line being modified and the other lines are 'unmodified' (no changes), even though I have modified the other lines.

An example:
[image: git diff result]

This is the change I have made to the document:
[image]

It only occurs on certain files and on other occasions, it will sometimes add the other lines, but it does not mark the appropriate line deletions. On other occasions, it will just append the changes at the end of the file, without marking it as an addition.

On SourceTree, it seems that the same diff does not make any sense too:
[image]

FYI: The files were originally downloaded from a Linux server.

Comment: What OS do you have locally?

Comment: @Mantas Running on Windows. Though on my remotes, it still shows the same corrupted diff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, after inspecting the offending files.

It seems that the files that were giving problems had a classic Macintosh `CR` only end of lines (EOLs) format. Contrast this to Window's `CR+LF` or UNIX's (and derivatives, including OS X) `LF`. Converting the file to Windows/UNIX EOL format, committing the fixed EOL files remedied the problem.

Testing it out with a test Git repository proved my suspicions right.

It might happen to be Git's way of tracking file changes, only supporting `CR` in combination with `LF` (`CR+LF`) and not `CR` alone (as what classic Mac uses).

Answer (score 0):

this is happening sometimes when your file is encoding with windows new line, on git it is encoded with unix new line, that's why you migth get this error, you have to configure your line endings to unix

EDIT :

this link [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/no-newline-at-end-of-file) could be usefull. Like he said in this post you can try depends on your editor to do :

> - For Vim users, you’re all set out of the box! Just don’t change your
>     eol setting. For Emacs users, add (setq require-final-newline t) to
>     your .emacs or .emacs.d/init.el file.
>
>   - For TextMate users, you can    install the Avian Missing Bundle and add TM_STRIP_WHITESPACE_ON_SAVE    = true to your .tm_properties file.
> - For Sublime users, set the ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save option to true.
> - For RubyMine, set    “Ensure line feed at file end on Save” under “Editor.”

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I found out it was the _other_ way round, those files in questions had Unix or Macintosh EOLs, not Windows.

Comment: the error no new line at end of file seems that files expects to have an extra blank line at the end of file.

Comment: This answer does not explain why his other changes are not showing in the diff.